# Determine relationship across two variables in simulation result data

Tags: interaction, simulation, variable

I need help, but I do not know the specific terms that describe what I want to do, but I will explain as much as possible. It is most likely the reason that I have not been able to get what I want, in case this same question has been asked here and answered in the past, kindly pardon me and direct me to where the solution is.

I do not have any sound statistics background although I have calculated standard deviation for the values and made some plots, but I still need help.

I am working on a simulation [50 iterations each] to determine the changes in a quantity A at container sizes [500, 1000, 2000 etc] and different percentages [1%, 2%, 3% etc] of another quantity B for each of the size.
[A combination of 1% and size=500, run 50 simulations, then pick a combination of 2% and size=500, run 50 simulations etc]

Size and percentage are categorical variables.

The raw simulation output for size 500 at the different percentages of quantity B is shown in the plot below. (Similar plots showing the simulation result for other sizes 1000, 2000 etc are also available)

The data below is a calculation of the standard deviation of the 50 data points from the 50 iterations for each combination of size and percentage

```
i   levels  size    sd
1       1%      sd_scf_500      0.000398498
2       2%      sd_scf_500      0.000316948
3       3%      sd_scf_500      0.000264636
4       5%      sd_scf_500      0.000526377
5       7%      sd_scf_500      0.000403608
6       10%     sd_scf_500      0.000409281
7       15%     sd_scf_500      0.00048844
8       20%     sd_scf_500      0.000743175
9       25%     sd_scf_500      0.000767954
10      1%      sd_scf_1000     8.89E-05
11      2%      sd_scf_1000     0.000118838
12      3%      sd_scf_1000     0.000105485
13      5%      sd_scf_1000     0.000178193
14      7%      sd_scf_1000     0.000237845
15      10%     sd_scf_1000     0.000196663
16      15%     sd_scf_1000     0.000304982
17      20%     sd_scf_1000     0.000235375
18      25%     sd_scf_1000     0.0003705
19      1%      sd_scf_2000     6.89E-05
20      2%      sd_scf_2000     2.88E-05
21      3%      sd_scf_2000     6.61E-05
22      5%      sd_scf_2000     7.24E-05
23      7%      sd_scf_2000     9.38E-05
24      10%     sd_scf_2000     0.000105725
25      15%     sd_scf_2000     0.000109742
26      20%     sd_scf_2000     0.000124143
27      25%     sd_scf_2000     0.000172164
28      1%      sd_scf_5000     2.21E-05
29      2%      sd_scf_5000     4.13E-05
30      3%      sd_scf_5000     2.76E-05
31      5%      sd_scf_5000     1.93E-05
32      7%      sd_scf_5000     3.18E-05
33      10%     sd_scf_5000     3.14E-05
34      15%     sd_scf_5000     4.71E-05
35      20%     sd_scf_5000     4.66E-05
36      25%     sd_scf_5000     6.74E-05
37      1%      sd_scf_10000    1.95E-06
38      2%      sd_scf_10000    1.62E-05
39      3%      sd_scf_10000    1.22E-05
40      5%      sd_scf_10000    1.37E-05
41      7%      sd_scf_10000    1.65E-05
42      10%     sd_scf_10000    1.07E-05
43      15%     sd_scf_10000    1.96E-05
44      20%     sd_scf_10000    1.74E-05
45      25%     sd_scf_10000    2.76E-05
46      1%      sd_scf_15000    8.53E-06
47      2%      sd_scf_15000    2.02E-06
48      3%      sd_scf_15000    6.20E-06
49      5%      sd_scf_15000    8.08E-06
```

[image: Plot of the output of the simulation]

What I am trying to do is 
1. determine if there is a relationship between the quantity A and the combination of size and percentage i.e. if the combination of size and percentage has an influence on the quantity A.
[In addition to this, is there a way to define a general trend about this relationship,if it exists, so that one can use it for later inference?]
2. Determine a way to quantify the changes to quantity A as "low" or "high"?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you doing your simulation by specifying a level and size and then doing 50 simulations. then moving to another combination of level and size?

Comment: Yes, a combination of level and size for 50 iterations and then moving on to another combination of level and size

Comment: And did you cut off at 49 to save space or because you really stopped at that 49th combination? Also, it would be more helpful to plot histograms (or better yet, densities) of the simulation results than the line charts you posted. The line charts make it look like there's some kind of time series component, and you probably consider your simulations independent of one another (within each level and size combination). The ggplot2 documentation will tell you how to make a density.

Comment: The simulation starts at 0 to 49, making 50 iterations. So there is no cutoff at 49. The data I displayed is just some of the data and not all of it.  I will consider the density plot.

Comment: How are you calculating the 49 rows in your "sd" column?

Comment: If I understand your question well, each combination of size and percentage has 50 values numbered from 0 to 49 (the 50 iterations). In order not to dump too much data here, this data shows a point from the 50 iterations for each of the size-percentage combination

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97688/discussion-between-dave-and-cephas).